# How to connect to a Ubuntu PC remotely by SSH

Tags: ssh, static-ip

Is it possible to connect to my desktop PC remotely, by SSH?

Which program should I use to make the IP address static that I will need to connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can! 
First `ifconfig` to get your IP address.

Then, to connect, you need to type in a terminal:

```
ssh username@address_ip
```

So, if for example your name is tommaso and your ip is 123.123.123.123 you need to type `ssh tommaso@123.123.123.123`.

It will ask you the user password, of course!

If you need graphical interfaces, add the `-x` option after `ssh`.

If it doesn't work, try to install `openssh-server` on the server side. Thus something like `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.