# How can I access another computer's terminal outside the local network?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I would like to access the terminal of another computer that is outside my local network.

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/q/683589/295286   Note however, that if the computer you want to access is behind a router on some other network, then you must have port forwarding on that router enabled

Comment: I think `ssh` will suits for this kinda behavior .. did u tyr that by adding the `ssh` key to th remote

Comment: @Serg what is the best solution if enabling port forwarding is not possible, e.g. because the other user does not know how to enable port forwarding in the router menu?

Comment: @orschiro  No other best solution, it has to be enabled. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases just as you are running under a local network the other computer might also be running under a local network.  That would make it impossible for you to connect directly that computer's IP unless the configured port forwarding of their router to go to that specific computer.

You could setup a common `VPN` (virtual private network) that would put both you and the other computer on the same network.  Then you would access the computer's IP (from the vpn) the same way you access computers on your local network.

Some information on setting up a `Virtual Private Network` can be found [here](http://faq.apollo3.com/ljames/ubuntu/vpn/).